# using an ios application as facebook application

Tags: ios, facebook, migrate

i am new for Facebook application designs. i search the net for my problem but could't find a solution.

I have recently created an iOS application. And i want to create same application with same resources as a Facebook application.

I wonder if there is an easy way for this besides recreating the application for Facebook? If there is not, what do you suggest me to do. I know objective-c, java, C++,C. which way could be easy for me?

Answer (score -1):

It is really difficult to understand what is the problem that you are facing, it would be really good if you can rephrase the question .,

Answer for the part i understood u want to integrate ur app with facebook you can try out following

[Facebook Ios SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)
[Facebook Ios Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/)

Comment: Thank you for answer. First of al my English is poor, sorry for that.

I already complated my application and integrated with facebook. It is working at iphone without problem. And now I want to do exact same application for facebook web application. And i wonder if is there any way to use my old objective-c codes at there. Or i should use php-javascript or other languages.